# MobaXterm - warn "are you sure you want to close this session"?

Tags: mobaxterm

Is there a way to make MobaXterm to popup a warning "are you sure you want to close this session" when hitting the "x" close button of a session tab?

Too often I accidentaly close my sessions :(

Answer (score 0):

-> Press 'Settings' icon on the top toolbar
-> Terminal
-> click checkbox 'Prompt before exit' at the right bottom